# Loop in a Windows Batch File

Tags: arrays, windows, loops, batch-file, iteration

I'm trying to create the following batch file:

```
@echo off

set "list=AICourse AIStudent Teacher"
set Server="localhost"
set Username="user"
set Password="()$rDCg3st@0"

    for %%n in (%list%) do (

        Set File=c:\temp\%%n.bcp
        Set Log=c:\temp\%%n.log_exp

        ECHO Begin BCP...: %TIME% 
        ECHO waiting...

        bcp Database.dbo.%%n OUT %File% -o %Log% -S%Server% -U%Username% -P%Password% -c

        ECHO End BCP..: %TIME% 
        ECHO Log in file %Log%

    )
```

However, when I try to iterate through the array, only returns the last result. How can I iterate then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this at the top of your script:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

And, then change all the `%Log%` instances to `!Log!` and `%File%` instances to `!File!`.

Comment: Adding that the tag %File% needs to be modified to!File! too. thanks.

Comment: Oops, I missed that one...added it to the answer.